# Substract rows in array without loops

Tags: python, numpy, background-subtraction

How can I subtract two rows in python `numpy`? without using loops

for example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2.2, 3.4, 5.2], [1., 5.4, 5.]])

# expected result:
y = [[-1.2, 2., -0.2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2.2, 3.4, 5.2], [1., 5.4, 5.]])
np.diff(x.T)
# array([[-1.2],
#    [ 2. ],
#    [-0.2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try subtracting with subtraction:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2.2, 3.4, 5.2], [1., 5.4, 5.]])
print(x[1] - x[0])
```